# ClassicalRegister gives out just one line instead of two

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

[image: Screenshot of my notebook]

Why do we have just one line here in `c0` and not 2?

Comment: You have correctly 2 classical bits!
Qiskit visualizes the classical bits always in *bundle*. 
The number "2" written on the classical line refers to the number of classical bits you have. You may ask why? Just for the sake of tidiness! Otherwise your visualization would get huge!

Answer (score 1):

By default, Qiskit visualization bundles together classical bits of the same register. If you would like to draw them separately, do

```
qr = QuantumRegister(2)
cr = ClassicalRegister(2)

circ = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
circ.draw('mpl', 
          cregbundle=False)
```

[image]